# How much watering is too much for seeds?

Tags: watering, seedlings

<sub>My translation of a local gardening newspaper:</sub>

> The soil mix needs to be slightly moist; however too wet a soil would rot the seeds.

It is implied all seeds are somewhat susceptible.

I attempt to keep the soil soaked about 30% of the time and have observed no severe failures.

- Need the seedling pots be turned into a permanent swamp to kill the seeds?
- Do all seeds react equally? Large seeds like acorns and chestnuts require additional treatment; instead my question is strictly about the quote from the newspaper.

Comment: What kind of seed?